# sidekiq running on more than one dyno

Tags: heroku, sidekiq

Currently I have a sidekiq process running on a single dyno on heroku that goes through every user in a table and syncs their mail with gmail:

Something along the lines of:

```
User.all do |user|
  # sync user's email
end
```

The process runs every 10 minutes but as you would expect, the more users we have, the more time it takes to sync and our users want to see their mail pretty quickly.

We want to scale out and increase the dynos.

Can anyone suggest a way that I can split the job over 2 dynos?

Should I have a separate query on each dyno that splits the users into 2 or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a scheduler job that runs every 10 minutes, and enqueues all users:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  # put job for this user in redis or something
end
```

then have your workers constantly fetching new jobs. Each job is then fetching/syncing the email for a single user, and not "all". Use `find_each` too so that you're not trying to load all users into memory ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches )

Re-architecting like this makes processing the sync/fetching easier to scale, as you can just add new worker dynos to increase throughput.